# Avoid showing cancel button on dialog

Tags: command-line, button, zenity

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 with:

```
$ zenity --version
3.28.1
```

I want to display a `--list` dialog with zenity, but I don't want to show the Cancel button (in fact I'm okay if there is no OK either). 
It should be easy with the `--no-cancel` option:

```
$ zenity --list --no-cancel
--no-cancel is not supported for this dialog
```

The output seems to indicate that zenity knows about the option but does not want to let me use it.

I only want to show the user the data in a table. I don't care about selection/editing or getting a result back.

Is there any alternative way? Or is `zenity` simply unable to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `zenity` is pretty limited. Luckily there’s a fork available which fills the gap: `yad` – “Yet Another Dialog” (`sudo apt install yad`). It uses the same syntax as `zenity`, but adds a ton of useful options, for example `--button` to explicitly define the buttons of your dialog window:

```bsh
yad --list --button=OK:0
```

This displays a list window with just an “OK” button returning the exit code `0`.

#### Example

Here’s a simple example inspired by one from the manpage:

```bsh
yad --list --button=OK:0 --checklist --column "Buy" --column "Item" \
  TRUE Apples TRUE Oranges FALSE Pears FALSE Toothpaste
```

[image: yad usage example]

When “OK” is clicked in this state the program returns a `0` exit code and prints the checked options to stdout:

```bsh
TRUE|Apples|
TRUE|Oranges|
```

#### Further reading

- [`man yad`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/yad.1.html)
- [Sourceforge project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/)
- [Usage Examples](https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/Examples/)

Answer (score 7):

## Relabel Zenity Cancel button

You can relabel the button but you can't remove it:

```
$ zenity --list --cancel-label="Go Back" --column="Column 1"
```

Will give you:

[image: zenity cancel relabel.png]

---

## YAD (Yet Another Dialog)

Both `yad` and `zenity` allow you to use GUI dialog boxes from a bash script or the shell command line. Yad surpasses Zenity in every department though:

```
sudo apt install yad
```

Works in all distros.

---

### Yad Progress bars

[image: yad progress bars.png]

You can define multiple progress bars in yad where zenity only offers 1. You can also include scrolling text.

---

### Yad buttons

[image: yad buttons.png]

You can assign any text you want to any button. Also notice you can include a Window icon too.

---

### Yad text entry

[image: yad text entry.png]

Yad displays text for you to change. Zenity cannot display existing text you can only enter new text.

---

### Yad support

The author of Yad and many more contributors answer your questions in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/yad-common). I've posted four or five questions about advanced functionality and usually get an answer within 24 hours. Not to mention enhancements are provided through the same channel.